A sum that includes product of binomial coefficients
I came across a sum involving a product of binomial coefficients during a computation.
For positive integers $m,n,j$, find the sum
$$\sum_{r=j}^{m}(-1)^{r-j}\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{j}.$$
Any help will be appreciated.

1/ What is $n$?  $\quad$ 2/ What have you tried? Did you calculate small values of $m, j$? If we removed the $(-1)^{r-j}$, is there a simplification?

$n$ is an integer. I have tried but this sum is more difficult than the involution identity because of $m$. If $m=n$ then the answer is the Kronecker delta.

Does $n$ compare to $m$ in any explicit way? In particular if $m>n$ then there are some terms that are zero, so I guess the interesting case is $m<n$, since you say the case $m=n$ is easy.

No, $m$ and $n$ are independents from each other.

Well, if $m>n$ then $f(m,n,j)=f(n,n,j)$, and you say you can get that, so WLOG you can assume $m<n$.

Yes, but I'm looking for a closed formula of any kind?

I claim that $$\sum_{r=j}^{m}(-1)^{r-j}\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{j}=(-1)^{m-j}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j-1}{m-j}$$
Here's a hint towards proving this. Try writing out that product of binomial coefficients in your sum and note that $r!$ cancels. Then see if you can massage the remaining term into a product of two binomial coefficients, one of which is independent of $r$.
If you still are unable to go forward, let me know in the comments!

$\sum_{r=j}^{m}(-1)^{r-j}\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{j}=\binom{n}{j}\sum_{r=j}^{m}(-1)^{r-j}\binom{n-j}{r-j}$ Thanks a lot!
